# Issue in Cypher Query - org.neo4j.internal.kernel.api.exceptions.EntityNotFoundException

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases, graph-data-science

I am performing below steps using cypher query. I am getting error in step 3. I have listed all steps below. Please help me to achieve expected output.

**Step 1- Load data and define properties of nodes relationship**

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file://nodes_1Jan22_full_v2.csv' AS row
CREATE (n: Organisation {id: row.organisation, esg_index: toFloat(row.tone)});


LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file://edges_1Jan22_full_v2.csv' AS row
MERGE (src: Organisation {id: row.src})
MERGE (dst: Organisation {id: row.dst})
MERGE (src)-[:RELATE {freq: toInteger(row.relationship), sentiment: toFloat(row.avg_tone)}]->(dst);
```

**Sample query and table structure**

```
MATCH p=()-[r:RELATE]->() RETURN p LIMIT 1
```

```js
{
  "start": {
"identity": 18862,
"labels": [
      "Organisation"
    ],
"properties": {
"id": "american university",
"esg_index": -3.005288932058546
    }
  },
  "end": {
"identity": 20048,
"labels": [
      "Organisation"
    ],
"properties": {
"id": "duke university",
"esg_index": -1.6810932825414502
    }
  },
  "segments": [
    {
      "start": {
"identity": 18862,
"labels": [
          "Organisation"
        ],
"properties": {
"id": "american university",
"esg_index": -3.005288932058546
        }
      },
      "relationship": {
"identity": 0,
"start": 18862,
"end": 20048,
"type": "RELATE",
"properties": {
"sentiment": -4.367701625823974,
"freq": 250
        }
      },
      "end": {
"identity": 20048,
"labels": [
          "Organisation"
        ],
"properties": {
"id": "duke university",
"esg_index": -1.6810932825414502
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "length": 1.0
}
```

**Step 2- Create graph projection**

```
CALL gds.graph.project(
    'gdelt-analytics',
    'Organisation',
    'RELATE',
    {
        relationshipProperties: 'freq'
    }
)

MATCH (org:Organisation {id: 'public health'})
CALL gds.pageRank.stream('gdelt-analytics', {
    maxIterations: 100,
    dampingFactor: 0.85,
    sourceNodes: [org],
    relationshipWeightProperty: 'freq'
})
YIELD nodeId, score
RETURN *
```

**Current Output**

[image]

**Step 3- Attempt to color node based on property "esg_index" and edges based on property "sentiment" (Query that is throwing error)**

```
CALL apoc.create.addLabels(n.esg_index, [apoc.text.upperCamelCase(n.id)]) YIELD node
RETURN *
```

> Neo.ClientError.Procedure.ProcedureCallFailed
> Failed to invoke procedure `apoc.create.addLabels`: Caused by: org.neo4j.internal.kernel.api.exceptions.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to load NODE with id -2.

**Expected Output**

Graph with nodes and edges colored. Nodes colored based on esg_index and edges colored based on sentiment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `APOC` `addLabels` function takes either a list of nodes or their id, which can be found using `ID(n)`, as its input. You are passing esg_index, that's why you might be getting this error:

Try this:

```
CALL apoc.create.addLabels(n, [apoc.text.upperCamelCase(n.id)]) YIELD node
RETURN *
```

It should work. [Documentation link](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.3/overview/apoc.create/apoc.create.addLabels/).

**Update:**

To add the label using esg_index, I think `apoc.do.case` function should do the trick for you. You can try something like this:

```
CALL apoc.do.case([
  n IS NOT NULL AND n.esg_index = -5,
  'SET n:DARK_RED RETURN n AS node',
  n IS NOT NULL AND n.esg_index = 1,
  'SET n:GREEN RETURN n AS node'
  ],
  'RETURN n AS node',{n: n})
YIELD value
RETURN value.node AS node;
```

Comment: I would like to color the nodes based on property value for example if esg_index is -5 then node color should be dark red as compared to nodes with  esg_index value being -3 or -2. If node value is positive then color should be green to dark green based on value.                                      I would also like to color edges based on same concept but with different property "sentiment"

Comment: I am getting error  --------------->

Neo.ClientError.Procedure.ProcedureCallFailed
Failed to invoke procedure `apoc.do.case`: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Can you share the complete stack trace here?

Comment: MATCH(n:Organisation)
CALL apoc.do.case([
  n.esg_Index = -5,
  'SET n:DARK_RED RETURN n AS node',
  n.esg_Index = 1,
  'SET n:GREEN RETURN n AS node'
  ],
  'RETURN n AS node',{n: n})
YIELD value
RETURN value.node AS node;

Comment: I have updated the case function if any error exception comes up. Please paste the whole exception here.

Comment: I am getting same error and window only shows that much error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245186/discussion-between-charchit-kapoor-and-carpe-diem).

Comment: Please can you help me finish it with edges part as well.                                                                 MATCH p=()-[r:RELATE]->() CALL apoc.do.case([ p.sentiment <0, 
'SET p:DARK_RED RETURN p AS edges', p.sentiment > 0, 'SET p:GREEN RETURN p AS edges' ], 
'RETURN n AS edges',{p: p}) YIELD value RETURN value.edges AS edges;

Comment: I am facing small issue in setting color property of "relationship". I have pasted in chat. Can you please look?

Comment: The query os working fine on my system. I have pasted a screenshot